Ollama Python Unable to set Client host, httpx.ConnectError
I'm trying to run an instance of ollama Client and set the host. As shown in the documentation Docs I see the code should work, but prociding any host but the OLLAMA_HOST environment variable (or 11434 as default if OLLAMA_HOST does not exist):
client = Client(host='http://localhost:11435')
gives me
httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
I found about this problem after I started using langchain for Python and stumbled accross this problem which I after further investigation I found it was due to ollama Python.
I put the code of an interactive session:
Python 3.10.12 (main, Sep 11 2024, 15:47:36) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> client = Client(host='http://localhost:11435')
    >>> response = client.chat(model='llama3.1', messages=[
    ...   {
    ...     'role': 'user',
    ...     'content': 'Why is the sky blue?',
    ...   },
    ... ])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 72, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    yield
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 236, in handle_request
    resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 216, in handle_request
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 196, in handle_request
    response = connection.handle_request(
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 99, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 76, in handle_request
    stream = self._connect(request)
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection.py", line 122, in _connect
    stream = self._network_backend.connect_tcp(**kwargs)
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/sync.py", line 205, in connect_tcp
    with map_exceptions(exc_map):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 14, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc) from exc
httpcore.ConnectError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ollama/_client.py", line 236, in chat
    return self._request_stream(
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ollama/_client.py", line 99, in _request_stream
    return self._stream(*args, **kwargs) if stream else self._request(*args, **kwargs).json()
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ollama/_client.py", line 70, in _request
    response = self._client.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 837, in request
    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 926, in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 954, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 991, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1027, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 235, in handle_request
    with map_httpcore_exceptions():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/bermudez/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 89, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.ConnectError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

After reading about ollama, I tried to change the OLLAMA_HOST env variable:
>>> import os
>>> print(os.environ.get('OLLAMA_HOST'))
None
>>> os.environ['OLLAMA_HOST'] = "http://localhost:11435"

and same error again, which I kind of expected, since the ollama library should handle this via the host parameter for Client.
The same happens in a Windows machine, but in this case the error is a bit different:
Errno 10061 : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

As I remember you need to start ollama server from the terminal. Run in terminal ollama run llama3:8b. Only then you'll be able to connect to the server from Python.

@tdimitch, I have the same problem. could you find an answer to this issue?

Fix for the Ubuntu Machine
before running the python script please make sure to install ollama in your machine using the below command
sudo snap install ollama

After installing the ollama pull the model that you want to load. In my case I am using llama3.1 so I run the below command to load the model:
ollama run llama3.1

After loading the model try to run the python script will run without the Connection Error.
